# Compiling header and cpp files in g++

Tags: c++, header, compiler-errors, g++, header-files

I have a problem to compile multiple files together using GNU g++, so please help me.

We assume there are five files:

```
main.cpp : the main function 
a.h      : the header file of class A 
a.cpp    : the definition of class A 
b.h      : the header file of class B 
b.cpp    : the definition of class B
```

In the program, `main.cpp` uses class A (thus including `a.h`) and class A uses class B (thus including `b.h`).

So, how do I compile this program to generate the executive file?

I tried to use the following command, but it feedbacked the error:

```
undefined reference to ~(objects in class A and B)". 
command: g++ -Wall -O2 -s main.cpp
```

And my operating system is ubuntu 12.04. I know if I make a project with stuff like dev c++ it will automaticly link files together but I don't want to use that. I've also seen other links and sources but I couldn't find something useful for myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
g++ -Wall -O2 main.cpp a.cpp b.cpp
```

This will create a program `a.out` which is the executable. The `-Wall` flag just tells the compiler to issue more warnings, and the `-O2` flag enables optimizations. The last three arguments are your source files. You need to give all source files that are not `#include`:d in any way to `g++`.

You can specify the executable name with the option `-o (name)`.

Comment: Sure. I added that info now. If you need even more details, try `man g++`.